# aptana studio 3 insufficient privileges to apply this update ubuntu

Tags: linux, ide, ubuntu-14.04, updates, aptana3

My ubuntu version is 14.04 and the current aptana studio 3 version is Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2.201308081805

When i try to update i get the following issue

[image]

Does any one have an idea on how to resolve this. Seems to be directory permission issue.

I provided full permission /opt/Aptana_Studio_3

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution , the problem was with the owner of the files , the files were having root as the owner.

2 options to solve this

1) Change the owner of all the files under /opt/Aptana_Studio_3 to the user you are using to work with Aptana. The command to be executed from the terminal would be

```
sudo chown -R currentuser:currentuser /opt/Aptana_Studio_3
```

change the 'currentuser' with your user

2) or execute the Aptana from terminal using root access with command

```
sudo /opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3
```

Then you would not find the error while making an update